# ng store in angular cli App not working for IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, polyfills

I am having trouble using ng store in the angular app while running it in IE 11. My angular verision and configurations are as bellow.

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 6.10.3
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.3
@angular/common: 4.2.3
@angular/compiler: 4.2.3
@angular/core: 4.2.3
@angular/forms: 4.2.3
@angular/http: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.3
@angular/router: 4.2.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3
@angular/language-service: 4.2.3
```

I have uncommented all the required core js library form **Polyfill.ts** file. I am trying to use ng store reducer and action to store the state into my angular app and while testing I found out that it is having trouble in IE 11.

FYI: I've tried importing promise in polyfill.ts file but that didn't solve the issue as well.

**Edit:** Below is my angular cli json file and

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"project": {
 "name": "app"
},
 "apps": [
  {
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "rcb",
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
    "scss/main.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
    "../node_modules/lscache/lscache.js",
    "thirdparty/js/datepicker.js"
  ],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  },
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "scss"
    ]
  }
}
],
 "e2e": {
   "protractor": {
   "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
  }
 },
"lint": [
  {
    "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  {
    "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
  },
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
}
],
"test": {
  "karma": {
    "config": "./karma.conf.js"
  }
 },
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "component": {}
 }
}
```

EDIT:below is my package.json file

```
{

      "scripts": {
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
        "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
        "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.3",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.4",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
        "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
        "ngx-order-pipe": "^1.0.2",
        "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
        "text-mask-core": "^5.0.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "lscache": "^1.1.0",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
        "tslint": "~5.3.2",
        "typescript": "~2.3.3"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "last 2 versions",
        "ie >= 11"
      ]
    }
```

EDIT: Polyfill.ts file

```
/**
     * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
     * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
     *
     * This file is divided into 2 sections:
     *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
     *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
     *      file.
     *
     * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
     * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
     * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
     *
     * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
     */

    /***************************************************************************************************
     * BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */

    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
    // import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


    /** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
    // import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



    /***************************************************************************************************
     * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
     */
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



    /***************************************************************************************************
     * APPLICATION IMPORTS
     */

    /**
     * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
     * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
     */
    // import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
    /**
     * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
     */
    // import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is upgrading your @angular/cli version to `"@angular/cli": "1.3.1"`, though 1.2.6 didn't have many bugs in this area (more bugs with aot than anything). If that doesn't work you'll need to post more info including any errors and details about what's failing.

Comment: That's the problem. I am getting no errors. it's just won't load values from redux that I am using. I will try to upgrade the angular cli version though

Comment: Add your package.json and .angular-cli.json, redux is not native (nor necessary in any aspect) to modern Angular apps

Comment: I've updated my question with the file you require. I may have removed some things like application name etc.

Comment: Lastly the polyfills.ts  if you don't mind.

Comment: added thepolyfill.ts file here

Comment: It's very likely to be an animations problem. I'd import the web-animations-js since you have animations imported into your projects. The other option may be to run with `ng serve --aot` and see if that changes anything (perhaps get some other errors). I need leave now, but hope this helps.

Comment: Any luck with this? :-)